# Interacting with a Smart Contract on private network through Web3.js

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have deployed my smart contract on private network using mist and geth.

Now confusion is that :  How can I interact with smart contract through Web3.js.

This is my script :

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract(YOUR ABI);

var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('PASTE CONTRACT ADDRESS HERE');
console.log(Coursetro);
```

When I tried below commands:

```
> web3.providers
{
  HttpProvider: function(host, timeout, user, password),
  IpcProvider: function(path, net)
}
```

Comment: I use infura. https://infura.io/.  Once setup you can use your infura link rather than the localhost link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you set up infura you can use the portal url that they return to you to create your provider.  just edit your script to look like:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(<your infura.io url here>));
        }
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract(YOUR ABI);

var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('PASTE CONTRACT ADDRESS HERE');
console.log(Coursetro);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I done signup on infura and got some urls from infra.
What I need to do next ?
Just Need to use those url on my scripts or setup my smart contract and infura ?

Comment: if you look at the code above you can see I just put the infura url in the place where I wrote <your infura.io url here> and that should configure your fallback if the user doesn't have a currentProvider.

Comment: No you don't have to use metamask to use infura.  If my previous response solved you issue please mark it as correct.  If not please ask clarifying questions.  Solidity development is sparse on resources so lets do our part to get answers out there.